# React Native iOS deep link only works when app is closed

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm testing out deep links using uri-scheme like this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#testing-with-npx-uri-scheme

I have tested on Android, but running into a problem for iOS.

If I have the app killed, then run the command, the app goes to the correct page with the deep link. But if I have the app open in the background and run it, the app opens and stays at the page it was before.

I followed the instructions for setup on iOS but I still can't get it to work properly when the app is open: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#setup-on-ios